# Reading nested directory with ContentNavigation component nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

My content folder has one directory called planets, which contains yaml files of different planets.

I want to render the planet pages as navigation items [content navigation component](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/components/content-navigation)

Currently i only get a link to the /planets page, so Im figuring that the component is reading the root content directory but I need to give it the /planets to read that instead.

In my index.vue file I have written this as per docs:

```
  <nav>
    <ContentNavigation v-slot="{ navigation }" :query="queryPlanets" >
      <div v-for="link of navigation" :key="link._path">
        <NuxtLink :to="link._path">{{ link.title }}</NuxtLink>
      </div>
    </ContentNavigation>
  </nav>

  <script setup>

     const queryPlanets = queryContent('planets')

  </script>
```

But I keep getting this vue router warn error:

```
[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/planets"
```

I have tried using the following:

```
const query = queryContent({
    where: {
      _path: { $contains: '/planets' }
    }
  })
```

Gives same error,

I have also tried to track the files down manually

```
 const query = await useAsyncData('planets', () => queryContent('/planets').find('/'));
```

And I do find the files with the right paths and all the values.

So I believe this is some sort of vue router error, but
I am unsure how to debug this exactly.

I am using Nuxt3

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when calling `<ContentNavigation v-slot="{ navigation }" >` you get everything including contents of nested directories.

So the navigation returns an object and then I can just write them out as follows:

```
<div v-for="dir in navigation" :key="dir._path" >
  <div v-for="link in dir.children" :key="link._path">
    <NuxtLink :to="link._path">
      {{ link.title }}
    </NuxtLink>
 </div>
</div>
```